# Delay download of .js file for last

Tags: javascript, html, css

My site requires one .js file for the site to work but uses another .js file for web analytics. Therefore, this last one is not really necessary so I would like the browser to load/download it after it has loaded/downloaded everything else: html markup, .css files and images. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3):

Yep:

```
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
.....
<script src="lastscript.js"></script>
</body>
```

Google also recommends a [deferred JavasSript loading technique](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/payload.html#DeferLoadingJS):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 // Add a script element as a child of the body
 function downloadJSAtOnload() {
 var element = document.createElement("script");
 element.src = "deferredfunctions.js";
 document.body.appendChild(element);
 }

 // Check for browser support of event handling capability
 if (window.addEventListener)
 window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
 else if (window.attachEvent)
 window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
 else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `DEFER` to the script tag that you want to have loaded/executed last.

```
 <script DEFER src="....js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm thinking about -1'ing you for offering an IE-only solution lol. That's just cruel ;)

Comment: @Alien +1 for being old school? :)

Comment: @Alien Perhaps -1 to Mozilla for adding DEFER(ish) support?

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion: Add an inline Javascript to your HTML file which waits for DOMReady event and than inserts the javascript tag for the second javascript lib into the head of your document.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
         var newScript = document.createElement("script");
         newScript.src = "address to your js";
         document.body.appendChild(newScript);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<head>
<script src="1"</script></head>
<body>
Your HTML here
<script src="2"></script>
</body>
```